# Random distinct numbers in Java

Tags: java, random, numbers

I have a problem generating random edges for not directed graph in Java. The problem is exactly the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793172/efficiently-generating-unique-pairs-of-integers), but I don't have a `randperm` function from matlab. I tried with creating a list of size `v*(v-1)*0.5`, where `v` is a number of vertices in graph, and shuffling it. However I'm trying to generate 100 million edges in graph with 1 million vertices. The list with about `10e12`entries is a real problem. So I need 100 million distinct numbers between `1` and `10e12` and have no idea how to get them.

Comment: Is your problem generating *distinct* numbers or generating *very large* numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating very large random numbers java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244691/generating-very-large-random-numbers-java)

Comment: I need large amount of distinct pairs of random numbers ( (a,b) and (b,a) is same pair )

Answer (score 0):

If you want a small sub-set of possible values without duplicates, a Set is a better approach.  This only has to retain the elements you have seen before to avoid duplicates.

```
Set<Long> longs = new HashSet<>(100_000_000*10/7); // for a load factor of 0.5
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++) {
    Long l = Math.abs(rand.nextLong() % 1000_000_000_000L);
    if (longs.add(l)) {
       // new long
    } else {
       i--;
    }
}
```

HashSet uses a lot of memory per entry so a more efficient solution is to use a primitive set such as [HashLongSet](http://openhft.github.io/Koloboke/api/0.6/java8/net/openhft/koloboke/collect/set/hash/HashLongSets.html) 100 million longs should use between 1 and 2 GB of memory.