# Generate cell with random pairs without repetitions

Tags: matlab, cell

How to generate a sequence of random pairs without repeating pairs?
The following code already generates the pairs, but does not avoid repetitions:

```
for k=1:8
    Comb=[randi([-15,15]) ; randi([-15,15])];
    T{1,k}=Comb;
end
```

When running I got:

```
T= [-3;10] [5;2] [1;-5] [10;9] [-4;-9] [-5;-9] [3;1] [-3;10]
```

The pair [-3,10] is repeated, which cannot happen.

PS : The entries can be positive or negative.

Is there any built in function for this? Any sugestion to solve this?

Comment: Do you have the Statistics toolbox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently generating unique pairs of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793172/efficiently-generating-unique-pairs-of-integers)

Comment: Thanks for the link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793172/efficiently-generating-unique-pairs-of-integers) but the solutions presented only work for positive combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Statistics Toolbox, you can use [`randsample`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) to sample `8` numbers from `1` to `31^2` (where `31` is the population size), without replacement, and then "unpack" each obtained number into the two components of a pair:

```
s = -15:15; % population
M = 8; % desired number of samples
N = numel(s); % population size
y = randsample(N^2, M); % sample without replacement
result = s([ceil(y/N) mod(y-1, N)+1]); % unpack pair and index into population
```

Example run:

```
result =
    14     1
    -5     7
    13    -8
    15     4
    -6    -7
    -6    15
     2     3
     9     6
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But only for positive combinations. And I also wanted for negative combinations.

Comment: @emanbap That's because you changed your question after I answered. Anyway, see edited answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ind2sub`:

```
n = 15;
m = 8;
[x y]=ind2sub([n n],randperm(n*n,m));
```

Comment: Best approach so far, in my opinion. `ind2sub` can be easily generalized to more than `2` components

Comment: Do you have to switch the input order to `ind2sub`?

Comment: @emanbap I updated the answer, as Jon noted the order of input to the ind2sub should be switched.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

1.

```
M = nchoosek(1:15, 2);
T = datasample(M, 8, 'replace', false);
```

2.

```
T = zeros(8,2);
k = 1;
while (k <= 8)
  t = randi(15, [1,2]);
  b1 = (T(:,1) == t(1));
  b2 = (T(:,2) == t(2));
  if ~any(b1 & b2)
    T(k,:) = t;
    k = k + 1;
  end
end
```

The first method is probably faster but takes up more memory and may not be practicable for very large numbers (ex: if instead of 15, the max was 50000), in which case you have to go with 2.